# multiple calls to procedure optimization

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, optimization

I have multiple python scripts running statistical tests and saving the results in a MySQL database.

I have chosen to create a procedure, making these scripts do lot's of calls, and only commiting in the end. (So that no info got lost, sometimes internet goes down and script gets corrupted, and other bugs)

The thing is, with this I can get multiple scripts running at the same time with some locking mechanisms, but after 3 or 4 scripts running, my server gets all 4 cores at 99/100% ...

Using `htop` it shows lots of mysqld processes and they all consume lots of CPU.

Anyone has any idea on how to optimize the CPU usage from mysql?

[my thoughts right now are instead of making multiple calls, create a multi-line insert, reducing the number of calls to mysql, but i'm not sure this would reduce CPU usage...]

**The query**

```
if( select exists(select id from frequency
                     where `title` like _title
                       and `subset` like _string) ) = 0 THEN
    insert into frequency(`title`, `subset`, `amount`)
                   values(_title, _string, _amount);
else
    update frequency set `amount` = amount+1
                     where `title` like _title
                       and `subset` like _string;
end if;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

High CPU usually implies `SELECT` with an inadequate index.

You mentioned inserts -- Yes, `INSERTing` 100 row in a single statement runs about 10 times as fast as 100 separate `INSERT` statements.  This is largely because of various overhead things that involve the CPU.  So, that should cut back on the CPU.

If you are doing any "normalization", consider doing it before entering the big transaction.  Ditto for anything else that might be "idempotent".

Comment: Yes, i had 2 selects, one to check if value existed or not, if it existed it would update one column, otherwise create the entire row...

The other select was just pure stupid to increment a value:
eg.
`
select value into var...;
set var = var+1;
update ... value = var...;
`


i removed the second , obviously to update / increment in a single statement, can i improve the exists(select ...) one?

Comment: Use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` for the first.  It can also be done in batch (multiple rows at once).  Show us the current queries if you would like help converting.

Comment: Adding the index improved the CPU usage in almost 90%!

Thanks :D

Comment: Didn't see your comment @Rick James, let me put it in a pastebin ;)

Basically I have a subset of words present in a title, and i want to count the amount of times that subset appears in a title. (just to give you the context)

#link: http://pastebin.com/1Z56FPzv

Comment: IODKU depends on there being a `UNIQUE` (or `PRIMARY`) key to know when to insert versus update.  Your test seems to disallow such.  Also, can't that `UPDATE` cause multiple rows to be matched?  And, perhaps you meant `+ _amount` instead of `+1`?

Comment: Actually I think you found a bug...
It would be: insert the amount, or add the amount to the previous value, so it would actually be amount + _amount :P

But yes, I have a unique key on the title, what i did was creating a key for the subset...


I just have one question: how does `insert .. on duplicate key update ...` works?
I will definitely look it up, but i have never heard of it

Thank you! :)

Comment: IODKU in a nutshell:  (1) check for duplicate key; (2) if dup found, do `UPDATE`; (3) if dup not found, do `INSERT`.

Comment: IODKU may not be useful to you -- you are not testing `title = _title`, which would test for dup.  Instead, you are testing for `title LIKE _title`, which could find multiple rows, not the one unique one.  (Don't use `LIKE` for 'equality' test.)

Comment: Well, the test can be changed, that's not the problem ... And is IODKU faster than my procedure, or is it just an "alias"?

I have some other procedures where IODKU seems to reduce my code ...

Comment: Each query requires a roundtrip to the server.  Each query needs to be parsed in turned into a execution plan.  So IODKU is faster since less of either needs to be done.  (Inside IODKU, the equivalent work is being done,)

Comment: Another advantage -- IODKU is atomic.  That is, if you had two connections with the same `_title`, both might try to `INSERT`; one would fail.  IODKU won't get into that situation.  (OK, "transactions" is a way to prevent this scenario.)

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for the insights, seems way better to use IODKU than what I have ! 

I think it will be very useful for me :D